# Notification being observed after removing

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am registering for notification in `viewDidAppear` and removing it in `viewDidDisappear`. But its being observed even after removal, I am unable to understand why. Here is my code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:Notification.Name(rawValue: kCustomNotification), object:nil, queue:nil) { notification in
        // my code
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(kCustomNotification)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Now I open the viewController screen using push, and then go back to previous controller but this notification is still being observed.

Comment: You can check, may be viewDidAppear is called twice.

Comment: Are you sure viewDidDisappear is called?

Comment: You added: `addObserver(forName:Notification.Name(rawValue: kCustomNotification)` but remove `.removeObserver(kCustomNotification)`. I think the problem is notificaiton name.

Comment: I have tested with breakpoints both methods are called once.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove observer for the name "kCustomNotification" in the same way as you added it thus

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) { 

  super.viewDidDisappear(animated) 

  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: 
  Notification.Name(rawValue: kCustomNotification), object: nil) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [addObserver:usingBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) method:

```
func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, 
          object obj: Any?, 
           queue: OperationQueue?, 
           using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol
```

To unsubscribe from the notification you should  [save returned object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver) and use it to unsubscribe:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   <...>
   if let observer = _observer
   {
      <unsubscribe>
   }
   _observer =  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(<...>)
   <...>
 }


  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    if let observer = _observer
    { 
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

You can find more examples in a discussion part in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver#Discussion):

> To unregister observations, you pass the object returned by this
>   method to removeObserver(*:). You must invoke removeObserver(*:) or
>   removeObserver(_:name:object:) before any object specified by
>   addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:) is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you add your observer in viewWillApper?